# Complex SQL query to Hibernate HQL statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Following SQL query:

```
select distinct hotel.country 'Country', hotel.id 'Hotel ID', hotel.Name'Name', room.id 'Room ID'
from room, stay, reservation, hotel
where
(stay.roomid = room.id) 
and (stay.reservationid = reservation.id) 
and (reservation.status != 'Booked' AND reservation.status != 'CheckedIn')
and (reservation.arrivaldate >= '2012-08-08')
and (reservation.leavedate <= '2012-08-15')
and (room.hotelid = hotel.id)
order by hotel.country, hotel.id, hotel.name, room.id asc
```

This will give me a list of available rooms per hotel per country. Now I have to put this in HQL, but I can't do so because of this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from room, stay, reservation, hotel where stay.roomid = room.id");
```

This doesn't work becuase `stay.roomid` is a Room object whereas `room.id` is just an integer. I'm pretty new to Hibernate/HQL and the reference manual didn't really bring me anywhere... How can I "convert" (scary word, I know this doesn't involve actual converting) this SLQ query to a HQL statement? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Using a join result in the same problem

```
Query query = session.createQuery("" +
                    "from Stay stay " +
                    "join stay.ReservationID reservation " +
                    "join stay.RoomID room " +
                    "join room.HotelID hotel " +
                    "where (stay.RoomID = room.ID)");
```

I'm really missing something (probably very logical) here...

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: You just didn't read the documentation correctly. Hibernate knows, from the mapping of the entities, that a stay and its room are linked with stay.roomId = room.ID. You don't need to tell it a second time in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your entities, but, just as you would use joins in SQL, you need to use joins in HQL:

```
select ...
from Stay stay
join stay.reservation reservation
join stay.room room
join rom.hotel hotel
where (reservation.status != 'Booked' AND reservation.status != 'CheckedIn')
and (reservation.arrivaldate >= '2012-08-08')
and (reservation.leavedate <= '2012-08-15')
```

The Hibernate documentation has a whole chapter on HQL, and a section of this chapter about [associations in HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: But what if I'd like to output the results of this query now? I can do a `Collection results = query.list();` but Iterating over those results doesn't allow me to cast the Objects to a Stay object (or any other of my objects for that matter)

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-tuples